# Apps script return values from server function to html form

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I need help of professionals at Apps script. I have the project implemented by web-app.
I wrote script on server-part

```js
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s8l-8N8dI-GGJi_mmYs2f_88VBcnzWfv3YHgk1HvIh0/edit?usp=sharing";
var sprSRCH = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
let sheetSRCHSSCC = sprSRCH.getSheetByName("PUTAWAY_TO");
 
function GetQ(){
  
  var QPLAN = sheetSRCHSSCC.getRange("M2:M").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var myArray = sheetSRCHSSCC.getRange("O2:O" + (QPLAN + 1)).getValues();
  
  var QFACT = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) { 
     if (myArray[i] != "") {
       QFACT += 1
     }
   }
   
}

I need to return values from this function to inputs:
QFACT to FACT
QPLAN to PLAN
```

```html
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input disabled value="" id="PLAN" type="text" >
              <label for="disabled">PLAN</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input disabled value="" id="FACT" type="text" >
              <label for="disabled">FACT</label>
            </div>
```

I will be grateful for the help. I'm new at this))

Comment: You could use templated html

Comment: What do you mean? How does it look?

Comment: It loads the data you want during the evaluate method server side before html is rendered.  Go to the documentation search and type in templated html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Apps Script deploying Web App, I can see 2 possibilities :

**1/ Get data at the loading of the page (and only at the loading) :**

In code.gs :

```
function doGet() {
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page');
  tmp.QFACT = "hello";
  tmp.PLAN = "World!";
  return tmp.evaluate();
}
```

In page.html :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h5><?= QFACT ?></h5>
    <h5><?= QPLAN ?></h5>
  </body>
</html>
```

**2/ If you need to refresh the data by click button, or something else, you will need to operate diffently :**

Add a page-js.html to your project, and bind it at the end of your page.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h5 id="QFACT"></h5>
    <h5 id="QPLAN"></h5>
  </body>
  <?!= include("page-js"); ?> 
</html>
```

then in your page-js.html :

```
<script>
  function refresh() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callback).refresh();
  }

  function callback(e) {
    document.getElementById('QPLAN').innerHTML = e.QPLAN;
    document.getElementById('QFACT').innerHTML = e.QFACT;
  }
</script>
```

and finally add the refresh() function in your code.gs :

```
  function refresh() {
    var obj = {};

    obj.QPLAN = "QPLAN";
    obj.QFACT = "QFACT";

    return obj;
  }
```

Comment: thank you very much. I'm going to take 2nd version)) Which function I must restart here periodically?

Comment: for refresh periodically, you have to add the function setTimeout() in the JS file.  Doc : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: setTimeout with miliseconds here?

Comment: Yes as mentioned in the doc :)