# Loading the arrays from server when DOMContentLoaded

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I try to get the contents of 3 arrays from spreadsheet in 3 vars when the page is loaded in DOMContentLoaded. But I get nothing (look the picture)

[image]

I deployed the test project here: https://script.google.com/a/fmlogistic.com/macros/s/AKfycbxROleHY3u69jTpdVZjLOfDTzY9c5q1S4kwm0ctTFzU/dev

and test-spreadsheet with script of this is here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qxr91eiLUykfLS0zKq3D4Dn206vnEkVqxDo6ZQF1rU4/edit#gid=0

I tried to write something like here, but this way with variantes [Apps script return values from server function to html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66686717/apps-script-return-values-from-server-function-to-html-form?noredirect=1#comment117883857_66686717)

```js
  const inputs = document.querySelector('.dws-input');
  const formControl = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');

  let findData;
  let curInpID;
  let firstValid, secValid, thirdValid, allValid;

  formControl[0].focus();

  function callBack(e) {
      var Logs = e.ListLogins;
      var Tabs = e.ListTables;
      var Ords = e.ListOrders;
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callBack).sendData();
    var Logs = e.ListLogins;
    var Tabs = e.ListTables;
    var Ords = e.ListOrders;
    console.log(Logs);
    console.log(Tabs);
    console.log(Ords);
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CLR: PACKING</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
       integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>      
</head>
<body>
    <div class="conteiner">
        <form novalidate>
            <h6 class="title">PACKING</h6>
            <div class="dws-input">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" novalidate id="tLogin" name= "username" placeholder= "Login:" autofocus > 
                        <label for="tLogin">Login:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  novalidate id="tTable" name= "text" placeholder= "Table:" >
                        <label for="tTable">Table:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input type="text"  novalidate class="form-control" id="tOrder" name= "text" placeholder= "Order:" >
                    <label for="tOrder">Order:</label>
                </div> 
            </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <?!= include("index-js"); ?>

</body>



</html>
```

In actions.gs at server I wrote this:

```js
  const url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
  var htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  let sheetTo = ss.getSheetByName("@sistem");
  let sheetIn = ss.getSheetByName("@packing");
  
function doGet(e){
    return htmlServ.evaluate();
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function sendData(){

  var lrLogins = sheetTo.getRange("A:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var arrLogins = sheetTo.getRange(1, 1, lrLogins, 1).getValues().flat();
  
  var lrTMPLORDS = sheetTo.getRange("K:K").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var curTMPLORDS = sheetTo.getRange(1, 11, lrTMPLORDS, 1).getValues();
  
  var lrTABLES = sheetTo.getRange("R:R").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var curTABLES = sheetTo.getRange(1, 18, lrTABLES, 1).getValues().flat();

  var objDataInfo = {};
  objDataInfo.ListLogins = arrLogins;
  objDataInfo.ListTables = curTABLES;
  objDataInfo.ListOrders = curTMPLORDS;
  return objDataInfo;
}
```

Are there any ways to get the contents of these arrays when the page is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   function callBack(e) {
      var Logs = e.ListLogins;
      var Tabs = e.ListTables;
      var Ords = e.ListOrders;
      console.log(Logs);
      console.log(Tabs);
      console.log(Ords);
   }


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callBack).sendData();
    //the following code is not in the callback function and it get's executed probably before the callback is returned.
    var Logs = e.ListLogins;
    var Tabs = e.ListTables;
    var Ords = e.ListOrders;
    console.log(Logs);
    console.log(Tabs);
    console.log(Ords);
  });
```

It could have been written like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(e){
    var Logs = e.ListLogins;
    var Tabs = e.ListTables;
    var Ords = e.ListOrders;
    console.log(Logs);
    console.log(Tabs);
    console.log(Ords);
  }).sendData();
});
```